# Show a hidden div after a form submit page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a div `result_head` which is hidden by default. Whenever I click a button which will provide options to select results, this hidden div will display as a heading for the form.

```
<div class="result_head" id="result_head" style="display: none"> >Results</div>
```

And the form code

```
<form method="post" id="form_result">

    <div class="form-group">    

    <-----some drop down menus here --------->

            <div class="form-group">

            <button type="submit" name="result_submit" id="result_submit"  style="display: none;margin:1%;" >Submit</button>

            </div>

        </form>
```

After the submit and after the page refresh, I need to display the heading for the result.
I tried different methods to achieve without any luck.

Tried Adding `onclick` and `onsubmit` finctions along with form submit

```
<button type="submit" name="result_submit" id="result_submit"  style="display: none;margin:1%;" onclick="document.getElementById('result_head').style.display = 'block';">Submit</button>
```

Tried to echo CSS in php to `display_head`.

```
<div class="result_head" id="result_head" style="display: none" <?php if (isset($_POST['result_submit'])){ echo 'style="display:block !important;"'; } ?> >Results</div>
```

Also found a method echo entire div via php after form submit which will create the new div after form submit. But that option is not feasible for me as I need to display the head before submit as well.

Also while looking into some solutions, found an option to change the button type from `sumbit` to `button` and use `jquery\ajax` to submit the form. I may have to change my entire code for that.

Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: You can not have twice the attribute *style* in an HTML tag

Answer (score 0):

after submitting form you can store value in `localStorage` for example

```
localStorage.setItem('isHeadingVisible', true);
```

and add code which will check in every page load is header visible or not by checking this

```
if(localStorage.get('isHeadingVisible')){}
```

you can read more about `localStorage` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

but this will not work if user will use another browser after these operations, because user's `localStorage` will be emty in new browser, so I would suggest to use backend data here, or check in every page load if `localStorage.get('isHeadingVisible')` is `undefined` and form is submitted, set `localStorage.setItem('isHeadingVisible', true);`

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
<div class="result_head" id="result_head" style="display: <?php echo ($_POST['result_submit'] ? 'block' : 'none') ?>">Results</div>
```

It just changes the style from `none` to `block` when submited.